# How to setup Masternode from Beginners?

Tags: blockchain, geek

I need a guide for single masternode, on an Ubuntu 16.04 64bit server (VPS) running headless and will be controlled from the wallet on your local computer (the Control wallet).

Thanks

Comment: What is a masternode? Which cryptocurrency or blockchain system?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to set up a Masternode
https://medium.com/geekcash/how-to-setup-masternode-from-beginners-ea5f60686790

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple way is using Bitcoin Core https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#ubuntu-1604